# how to change the default path of a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I am trying to draw a diagram with links between D --> B, and B --> E.
The figure below illustrates what I would like to get.
So, arrow which goes from D to B should not be in the middle south of B, rather some millimeters before the middle of B. And arrow going out of B to reach E should start some millimeters after the middle of B.

[image: goal image]

Here is my code, which unfortunately does not do what it should. All arrows go from the middle south of B.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw=black, thick, text width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center]  
\tikzstyle{arr} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[block] (A) {A};
    \node[block, below=of A] (D) {D};
    \node[block, right=of A] (B) {B};
    \node[block, right=of B] (C) {C};
    \node[block, below=of C] (E) {E};
    
    %\draw [arr] (D.east) --++ (15mm,0) |- (B.south);
    \draw [arr] (D) -| (B);
    \draw [arr] (B) |- (E);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that you can use just `++` in place of your `--++` , it would be correct even if the line is e.g. coloured or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution which doesn't make you create any more node is to use the `calc` library.

[image: calc to shift]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw=black, thick, text width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center]  
\tikzstyle{arr} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \node[block] (A) {A};
        \node[block, below=of A] (D) {D};
        \node[block, right=of A] (B) {B};
        \node[block, right=of B] (C) {C};
        \node[block, below=of C] (E) {E};
        
        \draw [arr] (D) -| ($(B.south)+(-5mm,0)$);
        \draw [arr] ($(B.south)+(5mm,0)$) |- (E);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of node `(B)`, use custom positions `(B1)` and `(B2)` made from `(B.south)` with `coordinate`.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw=black, thick, text width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center]  
\tikzstyle{arr} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[block] (A) {A};
    \node[block, below=of A] (D) {D};
    \node[block, right=of A] (B) {B};
    \node[block, right=of B] (C) {C};
    \node[block, below=of C] (E) {E};
    
    \draw
    (B.south) ++(-2mm,0) coordinate (B1)
    (B.south) ++(2mm,0)  coordinate (B2);
    \draw [arr] (D) -| (B1);
    \draw [arr] (B2) |- (E);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Result from MWE]

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to other answers but without using `calc` and without defining new `coordinates`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw=black, thick, text width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center]  
\tikzstyle{arr} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[block] (A) {A};
    \node[block, below=of A] (D) {D};
    \node[block, right=of A] (B) {B};
    \node[block, right=of B] (C) {C};
    \node[block, below=of C] (E) {E};
    
    \draw [arr] (D) -| ([xshift=-3mm]B.south);
    \draw [arr] ([xshift=3mm]B.south) |- (E);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]